# php string parsing to array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string that looks like:

```
'- 10 TEST (FOO 3 TEST.BAR 213 BAZ (\HELLO) TEST'
```

Same format for any other string. How could I get, the value of `FOO`, `BAR` and `BAZ`. So, for instance, I can get an array as:

```
'FOO' => 3,
'BAR' => 213,
'BAZ' => HELLO
```

Comment: explain the string pattern please

Comment: What kind of logic was/is behind the connection between the keys and the values???

Comment: pattern is basically as: `(CONST value X.CONST value CONST (\VALUE) X...)`, where `CONST` is the placer hoder in this case (never change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming neither the constants nor the values have space in them,
this will work for the given example  :

```
$str = '(CONST1 value1 X.CONST2 value2 CONST3 (\VALUE3) X...)';
preg_match('/\((\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+.*?\.(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\(\\\\(\S+)\)/', $str, $m);
$arr = array();
for($i=1; $i<count($m);$i+=2) {
  $arr[$m[$i]] = $m[$i+1];
}
print_r($arr);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [CONST1] => value1
    [CONST2] => value2
    [CONST3] => VALUE3
)
```

**explanation**

```
\(          : an open parenthesis
(\S+)       : 1rst group, CONST1, all chars that are not spaces
\s+         : 1 or more spaces
(\S+)       : 2nd group, value1
\s+.*?\.    : some spaces plus any chars plus a dot
(\S+)       : 3rd group, CONST2
\s+         : 1 or more spaces
(\S+)       : 4th group, value2
\s+         : 1 or more spaces
(\S+)       : 5th group, CONST3
\s+         : 1 or more spaces
\(          : an open parenthesis
\\\\        : backslash
(\S+)       : 6th group, VALUE3
\)          : a closing parenthesis
```

Answer (score 3):

[preg_match](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) is your friend :)

Comment: I think this answer is a bit too vague (as is the question). In lieu of a specific advise, here are some tools that might help OP with his issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Answer (score 1):

You want to use preg_match to first grab the matches and then put them into an array. This will give you what you are looking for:

```
$str = '- 10 TEST (FOO 3 TEST.BAR 213 BAZ (\HELLO) TEST';

preg_match('/FOO (\d+).+BAR (\d+).+BAZ \(\\\\(\w+)\)/i', $str, $match);

$array = array(
    'FOO' => $match[1],
    'BAR' => $match[2],
    'BAZ' => $match[3]
);

print_r($array);
```

This is assuming though that the first two values are numbers and the last is word characters.